# How to wrap another class (c++)

Tags: c++, class, c++11, wrapper

I'm trying to learn to c++ after programming in other OO languages for many years.

I'm trying to create a wrapper class for another class, but having a hard time figuring out how to set this up properly.

For instance, with the following...

main.cpp

```
#include "foo.cpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Foo foo(42);
  std::cout << foo.get_barx() << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "bar.cpp"

class Foo {
  public:
    // I'm trying to declare the member variable `m_bar` here.  I
    //   don't want to be instantiating an instance of Bar yet,
    //   but I think that might be exactly what's happening.
    Bar m_bar;

    Foo(int y) {
      // Here's where I really want to instantiate an instance of Bar
      //   and assign it to m_bar.
      Bar m_bar(y*2);
    }   

    int get_barx() {
      return m_bar.getx();
    }   
};
```

bar.cpp

```
class Bar {
  public:
    int m_x;

    // I seem to need this default constructor for the declaration
    //   of `m_bar` above, but I don't think that line should be 
    //   calling any constructors.
    Bar() { m_x = 21; };

    Bar(int x) {
      m_x = x;
    }   

    int getx() {
      return m_x;
    }   
};
```

When I compile and run this, I get back 21, but I expect 84. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, and I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with how I'm declaring the `m_bar` member variable in Foo, but I can't figure out what the right way is to accomplish this.

Comment: `Bar m_bar(y*2);` just creates a local variable. Use assignment.

Comment: By the way, the filename extension ".cpp" by very strong convention denotes an implementation file, one that's meant for separate compilation. Header files usually have extension ".h" or ".hpp".

Comment: Also, at the top of each header file, add a `#pragma once`, or alternatively use old-fashioned include guards (read up on them).

Comment: Ahah. Ok. changing `Bar m_bar(y*2)` to  `m_bar = Bar(y*2)` gives me the result I'm expecting ( thanks @Cheersandhth.-Alf ), but I think I'm still confused why the `Bar m_bar;` declaration needs a default constructor.  Maybe that's just something I need to learn to live with?

Comment: @JonGarvin I added an answer which should provide some clarity about the default constructor and initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### main.cpp

```
#include "foo.cpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Foo foo(42);
    std::cout << foo.get_barx() << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Here you should be including a header (e.g., rename "foo.cpp" to "foo.h"). In general, the header provides the declaration and the source (e.g., .cpp file) provides the definition/implementation.

### Bar.cpp (again this should be a header)

```
class Bar
{
public:
    int m_x;

    // A default constructor is not required, however defining any constructor
    // prevents auto generation of the default constructor

    Bar(int x) : // This starts the initializer list section
        m_x(x)
    {
        // This is assignment not initialization
        // m_x = x;
    }   

    // See the trailing 'const', research const correctness
    int getx() const
    {
        return m_x;
    }   
};
```

### foo.cpp (again this should be a header)

```
#include "bar.cpp"

class Foo
{
public:
    // Just declaring a `Bar` data member
    Bar m_bar;

    Foo(int y) :
        m_bar(y) // Initialize `Bar` data member using the available constructor
    {
        // First, this declares a new `Bar` instance which is different than
        // the class member, regardless of the fact they are named the same
        // Bar m_bar(y*2);

        // Furthermore, even if you did the following it is assignment not initialization
        // m_bar = Bar(y*2);

        // Since initialization already occurred before this point an error
        // will result if the `Bar` data member isn't instantiated via the
        // only available constructor, since there isn't a default constructor as
        // explained above
    }   

    // Same comment about const correctness
    int get_barx() const
    {
        return m_bar.getx();
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use initialization lists to construct class members at construction time.  The body of the constructor gets called after all members have been constructed.  If you don't explicitly call a non-default constructor then the compiler will insert a call to the default constructor for you.  For example, your `Foo` class could look like:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int y) : m_bar(y*2) {}
    ...
private:
    Bar m_bar;
}
```